# Is there a good way to refactor methods that use duplicate conditional statements?

Tags: java

I have two similar methods with duplicate conditions and duplicate else blocks.  I'd like to refactor this to share the same logic and else blocks, but call the different methods.  How can I do this?

```
public void entryPoint1(...)
{
    if(nullCheckStuff) {}
        method1(stuff);
        method2(stuff);
    } else {
        //log error
    }
}

public void entryPoint2(...)
{
    if(nullCheckStuff) {
        method2(stuff);
    } else {
        //log error
    }
}
```

Comment: You could take out the `if block` code to another function that receives 1) the condition and 2) the entrypoint which came from, so from there you can decide if the other method should be executed

Comment: can you show us little bit in detailed example

Comment: @B.J.A.A. - I concur, but the 2nd argument should be something like ```boolean callMethod1``` rather than ```boolean fromEntryPoint1``` -- i.e., describe its effect rather than who's asking.

Comment: @another-dave that's ok if he only will have 2 entrypoints but if the entrypoints grows the boolean will not be enough to make a decision

Comment: At that point, having a method that does different things depending on who calls it has become a badly-structured mess.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you use Java 8 or above, a possible solution would be to use lambdas.
You define internal function with the common logic, which takes a Runnable as an argument:

```
private void commonLogic(Runnable action)
{
    if(nullCheckStuff) {
        action.run();
    } else {
        //log error
    }
}
```

Then your original functions look simply like:

```
public void entryPoint1()
{
    commonLogic(() -> { method1(); method2()});
}

public void entryPoint2()
{
   commonLogic(() -> method2());
}
```

You will also probably need to add more parameters to `commonLogic()` function to pass data required for `nullCheckStuff` expression and error handling block.

Answer (score 0):

So you have your code like this:

```
public void entryPoint1(...)
    {
        if(nullCheckStuff) {}
            method1(stuff);
            method2(stuff);
        } else {
            //log error
        }
    }

public void entryPoint2(...)
    {
        if(nullCheckStuff) {
            method2(stuff);
        } else {
            //log error
        }
    }
```

You have to take out the if block and put it in another function, let say `checkNullStuff()`:

```
public bool checkNullStuff(<object, string, whatever> condition, int entrypoint) {
    bool everythingOk = true;
    //checks if null
    if(condition) {
      return !everythingOk;
     }
    //executes common methods
     method1(stuff);
    //if not empty check what to do

    switch(entrypoint) {
      case 1:
         method2(stuff);
        break;
      case 2:
        method3(stuff);
        break;
      default:

        everythingOk = false;
    }
    return everythingOk;
}
```

Why i used a switch instead of an if, well if your entrypoints grows and more common methods are needed to be executed
and the entrypoint function:

```
public void entryPoint1(...)
{
    // here we check if went wrong, otherwise the functions were executed
    if(!checkNullStuff(nullCheckStuff, 1)) {}
       // code for when nullCheckStuff was not what we exepected
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If your methods doesn't already have too much parameters, you could refactor that way:

```
public void commonEntryPoint(..., boolean m1Condition) {
    if(nullCheckStuff) {
        if (m1Condition) {
            method1(stuff);
        }
        method2(stuff);
    } else {
        //log error
    }
}
```

Cheers!